# What tense is "My father is here."?

Tags: present-tense

My question is regarding the use of verb to be and tenses. Sentences like:

1. > The increasing occurrences of alien sightings **are** unproved.
2. > My father **is** here, now.
3. > They **are** nice people

Are all of these sentences in the present simple tense?

Comment: Welcome to ELL. Yes, they are all **simple present tense**, though a question like this can usually be found with a simple search.  You have posted correctly and given a few examples which is always a good thing to do. We look forward to your next questions which may be less obvious to search for.

Comment: You've started off very well, keep going!

Comment: @Peter I'm not sure it's that quite so straightforward :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you see a sentence or clause with the word *am*, *is* or *are*, then the clause is present tense.

If this word is not followed by an *-ing* form of the verb but a noun phrase, adjective phrase, or preposition phrase, for example, we say that it is present *simple*:

- I am **a teacher**.
- I am **hot**.
- I am **in the kitchen**.

If the word *am, is* or *are* is followed by a past participle, then it is part of a passive sentence. This sentence would also be considered a present simple:

- Rice is **eaten** all over the world.

When one of these three words is followed by an *-ing* form of the verb, we say that it is part of a present *continuous* construction:

- I am reading Araucaria's post.

Comment: Thank you, Araucaria. But I'm a bit confused right now. You said present tense then present simple, is there a difference?

Comment: @SaraNaseem In English we only have two tenses the present and the past tenses. But there are different present tense constructions we can use. The "present continuous" uses the present tense of the verb *BE* and a verb in the *-ing* form. It usually presents the action as happening now: *I am typing*. When we just use one verb on its own in the present, we consider this a "simple" construction. We usually use this to talk about things that happen, often, usually or always: *I like cheese*.

Answer (score 1):

Be is used as a main verb (full verb) or an auxiliary (helping) verb.

The sentences presented are in the simple present in which we use is, are, and am. These verbs when used as main (full) verbs indicate the existence of some person or thing. In the past simple, we use was and were. Sometimes, we call the verb "be" a copula or linking verb when used as a main verb.